# How much does "can" change my meaning?

Tags: grammar, differences, tenses

How much of a difference in meaning is there between these three sentences, and are any of them better suited to formal writing than the others?

> 1. They must [do things] before they can begin to understand these concepts.
> 2. They must [do things] before they can understand these concepts.
> 3. They must [do things] before they understand these concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They must [do things] before they can understand these concepts.

This one is probably that which says precisely what you mean without either excess or ambiguity.

> They must [do things] before they can begin to understand these concepts.

The *begin* provides emphasis, but seems a bit needless. I'd use it if I meant it literally. Conversely if I really did want to pile on emphasis (e.g. I was responding to someone who disagreed with the need for [do things]) I'd go all out and use "can even begin to".

> They must [do things] before they understand these concepts.

Ambiguous with the idea that the time when they understand the concepts acts as a deadline by which time they must [do things]. It's not a very readily available misreading, so I don't think this ambiguity is a major problem, but it's enough to make me lean against it.

> are any of them better suited to formal writing than the others?

I'd favour the second in any register.

My "can even begin to" alternative (again, only suitable if I've a strong reason for such emphasis) I'd be less likely to use the more formal I wanted to be; not ruling it out in any register, but the more formally I was writing the more I'd only do so when opposed to another opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The word *can* as used in your sentences is equivalent to saying:

> ..before it is possible for them to understand these concepts.

Without the use of *can*, it means that they must [do things] before they *will* understand these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest number 2 in the most formal contexts. Number 1 isn't exactly infrmal but it might be excessively rhetorical in tone. Number 3 has a somewhat different implication, which in a formal context might be picked up on, whereas in an informal context it might be overlooked.

> 1. They must [do things] before they can begin to understand these concepts.
>
>    = It is impossible to start the process of understanding the concepts until they have done these things.
> 2. They must [do things] before they can understand these concepts.
>
>    = It is impossible to completely understand the concepts until they have done these things.
> 3. They must [do things] before they understand these concepts.
>
>    = (Literally) It is in theory possible to completely understand the concepts before they do these things but they are nevertheless obliged to do them first.